# Javascript/HTML works in everything except IE9 and the really old IEs

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer-9

[www.americanmedicalbuildings.com/ourwork.html](http://www.americanmedicalbuildings.com/ourwork.html)

Ever since updating to HTML 5, under "Portfolio" - i.e. view by type..I can't get the pull down menu to work on IE9.  It works on Opera, Safari, Chrome, IE8, Firefox, and Mobile devices.

I also get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

```
    // JavaScript Document

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
} 

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
   var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-     2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src;    x.src=a[i+2];}
}

function showLayer(whichLayer){
    document.getElementById(whichLayer).style.display = "block";
}

 function hideLayer(whichLayer){
    document.getElementById(whichLayer).style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Mickey Mouse Code. People still use Dreamweaver generated JavaScript? Upgrading to HTML5, you changed the page's doctype?

Comment: Please don't ask people to reverse-engineer your page. Please post the relevant code in your question. Also, depending on Macromedia scripts is a bad idea.

Comment: Um ya... can we all agree to stop using dreamweaver-generated code?  And then wonder why it's not working?  *facepalm*

Comment: what is wrong with changing page's doctype?

Answer (score 2):

You have a bug in the MooTools Library that is trying to create an element

```
SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5)
```

You will need to upgrade the mootools version to get rid of the error since the version you have does not support IE9.

Comment: I just updated mootools to new version but not working on any browser now